# Tikz: How to fit also the text of a node inside a box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Assume I want to cluster certain nodes in a box, **however I also want the node text to get boxed.**

The following MWE place the node in the box, however the below (or left/top/right) placed text, not.

How to get wrapped up everything associated with a node?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',semithick,auto]
    \tikzstyle{surround} = [fill=blue!10,thick,draw=black,rounded corners=2mm] 
    \tikzstyle{obj}  = [circle, minimum width=10pt, draw, inner sep=0pt]
    \node[obj,label=below:Outside] (id1) at (2,2)  {}; 
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background} 
   \node[surround] (background) [fit = (id1)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can name the label and add to the `fit` list.

```
\node[obj,label={[name=id1-l]below:Outside}] (id1) at (2,2)  {}; 
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background} 
  \node[surround] (background) [fit = (id1)(id1-l)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

If you are going to use this often times then making a style out of it might be a good idea.

[image]